# RestAPISDK .Net Execute Payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to implement Paypal in an ASP.Net website. I've installed the RestAPISDK and I've been following this guide by Paypal (https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/dotnet) as well as looking at the references located here (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment)

So far it's going well, but upon returning from Paypal's website, I'm not able to execute the payment as per their documentation.

The Guide says to use the following code

```
Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
string accessToken = "TOKEN";
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;

Payment payment = new Payment("PAYMENT ID");
PaymentExecution pymntExecution = new PaymentExecution();
pymntExecution.payer_id = ("DYRNAJP829GTN");
Payment executedPayment = pymnt.Execute(apiContext,pymntExecution);
```

But Payment has no constructor that take in the Payment ID.

The Rest API Reference says to use the following method

```
Payment payment = Payment.Get(accessToken, "Payment ID");
```

However, Payment.Get is depreciated. If I use it anyway I just get an Exception saying the server responded with a 404.

What are we supposed to use instead? I can't find any up to date documentation to point me in the right direction.
I'm thinking I may have to use HttpClient to send the Request myself but surely I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the PaymentHistory retrieval method that is deprecated in favor of the Payment.List() method. To retrieve a single payment, you still use the [Payment.Get](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/PayPal/Api/Payments/Payment.cs#L149) method.

Are you sure you are passing in a valid payment id for the second parameter here? A 404 (Not Found) error is thrown when a payment with the passed in ID does not exist.

Comment: I see now. I was using the token that came back. Tried using the PayerID too which I knew wouldn't work.

Comment: Here's the code. Running in Sandbox mode, I get a token and PayerID back. I use the token in the Payment.Get method but this is what happens http://i.imgur.com/fsuaz6w.png

Comment: So you don't use the token (EC-****) value in your Payment.Get call, you pass in the original payment id (PAY-****) from the Payment.Create call

Comment: Ah, I see now. What an idiot. lol. I'll need to figure how to securely do that.

Comment: The biggest problem is, that they still havent updated their examples. Their examples does not work. You asked this question okt 2013, now is okt 2014, and no change..

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the C# samples do not work and produce the same 404 exception when you try to Execute a payment with your own sandbox store.

What you need to do is:

`Payment payment = Payment.Get(context, paymentID);`

where context is your apiContext and paymentID is the id passed back in by the return url from PayPal.

you then need:

```
var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution
                {
                    payer_id = payerId
                };
```

finally you can then call:

```
payment.Execute(context, paymentExecution);
```

this returns a payment object, which should have the 'state' of approved...